# Are there APIs for the PayPal.Me? (PayPal.me is another payment feature thru links)

Tags: c#, .net, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I would like to ask if there are any APIs for the PayPal.me.

I had tried several PayPal APIs implemented in .NET and though I was able to send payments using the .NET SDK, I wanted to use the PayPal.me feature where the Payer would just need to click the LINK of the Payee and enter the amount, below is the link to Paypal.me:

https://www.paypal.me/

Thanks.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to retrieve the PayPal.me link for a user via an API so you can directly use it in your application.
PayPal.me links can only be generated through their website and is purely browser based.

For reference, see [here](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Sandbox-Environment/Create-paypal-me-accounts-via-API/td-p/1491113)